# Custom config section in app.config with common elements to iterate

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm wondering whether it's possible to create a custom section in app.config that would look like this:

```
<users>
   <user name="guest">
      <add key="" value="">
      <add key="" value="">
   </user>
   <user name="admin">
      <add key="" value="">
      <add key="" value="">
   </user>
   <user name="moderator">
      <add key="" value="">
      <add key="" value="">
   </user>
</users>
```

I don't want to use unique sections for each user, as I want to iterate through "users".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GetSection method on AppSettings.  Example code on MSDN for that methd has example on how to get the raw XML for the section, which you can then iterate as XML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's not a bad idea. Thanks!